# Display image using echo in tables in multiple yet continuous rows and columns

Tags: php, html-table, echo, multiple-columns, rows

I managed to display the images from the database however it just displays continuous without any format in a table. Do I have to do an extra if loop or while loop?

```
<table cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0'>

<?php
include 'dbFunctions.php';
$arrStocks = executeSelectQuery("SELECT name,id,image,price FROM stocks");

for ($countStocks = 0; $countStocks < count($arrStocks); $countStocks++) {
  $name  = $arrStocks[$countStocks]['name'];
  $image = $arrStocks[$countStocks]['image'];
  $id    = $arrStocks[$countStocks]['id'];
  $price = $arrStocks[$countStocks]['price'];
?>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="timgG">
        <h4><?php echo '<img src="stocks/' . $image . '">' ?></h4>
      </th>
      <th class="timgG">
        <?php echo '<a href="stockDetails.php?id=' . $id . '">' . $name . '</a>'; ?>
      </th>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you explain the "it just displays continuous without any format in a table" part, please? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It means that by using the above code, it just display as a single column. And I want the images to display with multiple rows and columns instead of just one column. @JérémieAstori

Comment: I still don't get what you are trying to achieve. I tred it using some fake data. Apart from the missing `</thead>` in the loop as @FaCE mentioned (as well as semantic weirdness), I have several rows, each one of them being made of two columns (the first one is the image, the second one is the link).

Comment: I'm trying to achieve something similar to those what you see on online stores where they display images and text in tables @JérémieAstori

Comment: See answer below, I tried something, hope it helps

Comment: did my answer help? If so, don't forget to accept the answer that helped you, and maybe give an upvote... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is going to output something that looks like

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th><h4><img /></h4></th>
    <th><a>...</a></th>
  </tr>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th><h4><img /></h4></th>
    <th><a>...</a></th>
  </tr>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th><h4><img /></h4></th>
    <th><a>...</a></th>
  </tr>

  ... 
</thead>
```

Which is not well formed HTML. I don't think you need to have images in headers or every row of your table being a table column header.

Instead, try using `<td></td>` rather than `<th></th>` and put your opening `<thead>` outside of your for loop.

You might also want to consider what your table headings are going to be -- if they're the first row in your `arrStocks` query, then you could add an if statement to change the output of your first table row to make them `<th></th>`, but again, I'm not sure why you'd need to define an image as a table header.

**Edit**

The only other thing that might break your table output is the content of your include.

try:

```
<?php
include 'dbFunctions.php';
$arrStocks = executeSelectQuery("SELECT name,id,image,price FROM stocks");
?>
<table cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0'>
<?
for ($countStocks = 0; $countStocks < count($arrStocks); $countStocks++) {
  $name  = $arrStocks[$countStocks]['name'];
  $image = $arrStocks[$countStocks]['image'];
  $id    = $arrStocks[$countStocks]['id'];
  $price = $arrStocks[$countStocks]['price'];
?>
    <tr>
      <td class="timgG">
        <?php echo '<img src="stocks/' . $image . '" alt="">' ?>
      </td>
      <td class="timgG">
        <?php echo '<a href="stockDetails.php?id=' . $id . '">' . $name . '</a>'; ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: What does the rest of the page look like? Is there any CSS?

Comment: Ok, noted. Thanks for that. Back to what I am trying to achieve, I want it to echo out something that will give me an output of this

    '<table>'
    '<thead>'
    '<tr>'
    '<th class="timg"><img.jpg></th>'
    '<th class="timg"><img.jpg></th>'
    '<th class="timg"><img.jpg></th>'
    '</tr>'
    '<tr>'
    '<th class="timg"><img.jpg></th>'
    '<th class="timg"><img.jpg></th>'
    '<th class="timg"><img.jpg></th>'
    '</tr>'
    '</thead>'
    '</table>'

Comment: I'm trying to achieve something similar to those what you see on online stores where they display images and text in tables @FaCE

Comment: thanks for the edited answers but it still doesn't come out as what I want.. -FaCE

Comment: what i want is like 

image1 image2 image3 image4
image5 image6 image7 image8
continue......... @FaCE

Comment: @nurf Can you give me a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of what your outputted code will look like?

Comment: it will be like image 1, image 2, image 3   (next line followed by other images aligned with the above and so forth) @FaCE

Answer (score 0):

If I properly understood what you asked, you want a grid of images. A grid is a 2-entry table, so you need to have 2 loops indeed. Every entry of a row (that is, every column) comes from a first loop, every row comes from a second loop calling the first loop inside.

I will go for this next snippet. There are some unknown constraints you did not give though, so I will assume some of them.
For example, I will assume that your data is returned as an unidimensional array.

```
<?php
$data = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six');
$nbColumns = 3;
?>

<table>
  <?php
    for($row = 0; $row * $nbColumns < count($data); ++$row) {
  ?>
  <tr>
    <?php
    for($col = 0; $col < $nbColumns; ++$col) {
    ?>
      <td><?php echo $data[$row * $nbColumns + $col]; ?></td>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
  </tr>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
</table>
```

This will produce:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>four</td>
    <td>five</td>
    <td>six</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You should be able to adapt this snippet to your needs.

Please tell me if there is something you need me to explain so that I can edit my answer/snippet.

---

**EDIT:**

I am not sure to get what you need me to explain.

Anyway, I simply reinjected your initial code in my snippet, but I did not do anything special. Basically, I just inserted the `include` and call to `executeSelectQuery` at the top and replaced the dumb numbers with your two lines, first will be the image and second will be the link/name.

This should work as is, bu I cannot guarantee it will since I do not have all the details of your code.

```
<?php
include 'dbFunctions.php';
$arrStocks = executeSelectQuery("SELECT name,id,image,price FROM stocks");
$nbColumns = 3;
?>

<table>
  <?php
    for($row = 0; $row * $nbColumns < count($arrStocks); ++$row) {
  ?>
  <tr>
    <?php
    for($col = 0; $col < $nbColumns; ++$col) {
      $index = $row * $nbColumns + $col;
      $name  = $arrStocks[$index]['name'];
      $image = $arrStocks[$index]['image'];
      $id    = $arrStocks[$index]['id'];
      $price = $arrStocks[$index]['price'];
    ?>
      <td>
        <img src="stocks/<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>">
        <br>
        <a href="stockDetails.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a>
      </td>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
  </tr>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
</table>
```

As a conclusion, please note that you should not use a `table` to achieve what you want. My answer is a bit hackish (the `$nbColumns` is not very nice) but there is not much of a better way to achieve what you want using the `table`s.
Using `float`s might be a better solution though, but it would not be a PHP related problem anymore...

---

**EDIT2:**

Edited and tested my last snippet, it works now ;-)

Comment: i get what you mean but how do i apply to my codes? you can refer to my codes at the top of this page, 

$arrStocks = executeSelectQuery("SELECT name,id,image,price FROM stocks");
...... @Jérémie Astori

Comment: Please do not forget to upvote the answers that were useful and appropriate to you, and to accept the answer that actually gave you a solution ;-)

Comment: it came out as image1 image1 image1 (next line)  image2 image2 image2 (next line)  image3 image3 image3. somewhat it works but what i wanted specifically is that whatever i stored in the database, the output will be image1 image2 image3 (next line) image4 image5 image6 (next line) so on and so forth.. is there a way to it? @Jérémie Astori

Comment: and if i dont capture it in a table, what do you suggest? float is one but im not sure what you meant @Jérémie Astori

Comment: Oops, my bad, I made a mistake indeed, it should be better now.

Comment: What to use instead of a table is not the same problem, please accept answer first :-) Then, send me an email (firstname at lastname dot fr) and we will extend the discussion if you wish.